# Best practice of sending data of different sizes over the network

Tags: c, networking, udp

I want to send data in varying sizes over UDP. The size of data to be sent is not fixed. I have the following scenario:

```
unsigned char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
int bytes = fill_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer)): // Returns number of filled bytes.
sendto(socket, buffer, bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))
```

In the example above, receiving side does not know how many bytes to receive. I also thought of first sending the number of bytes to receive and then sending the data. But in that case, I don't know what would happen if the packets arrive out-of-order.

**Sender side** would be

```
sendto(socket, &bytes, sizeof(bytes), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))
sendto(socket, buffer, bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))
```

**Receving side** would be

```
recvfrom(socket, &bytes, sizeof(bytes), 0, NULL, NULL)
recvfrom(socket, buffer, bytes, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

But could it be that sent data comes out-of-order?

Comment: You need to create an application-layer protocol, and it could include a sequence number so that you could reorder any out-of-order data. Also, remember that UDP _will_ have lost datagrams, so you must either accept the fact that not all data will make it across, have an application or application-layer protocol that can request lost data be resent, or use something like TCP that does all that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can send *both* in a single datagram if you add a message header.

The sender only sends the amount of payload data it has.

The receiver always requests the *maximum* payload size but examines the header and the return from `recvfrom` to determine the actual length.

---

Here's some rough code that illustrates what I'm thinking of:

```
struct header {
    u32 magic_number;
    u32 seq_no;
    u32 msg_type;
    u32 payload_length;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

#define MAXPAYLOAD  1024

struct message {
    struct header info;
    unsigned char payload[MAXPAYLOAD];
} __attribute__((__packed__));

void
sendone(int sockfd,const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    struct message msg;
    static u32 seqno = 0;

    memcpy(&msg.payload[0],buf,buflen);
    msg.info.magic_number = 0xDEADADDE;
    msg.info.seq_no = seqno++;
    msg.info.payload_length = buflen;

    sendto(sockfd,&msg,sizeof(struct header) + buflen,...);
}

ssize_t
getone(int sockfd,void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    struct message msg;
    ssize_t rawlen;
    ssize_t paylen;
    static u32 seqno = 0;

    rawlen = recvfrom(sockfd,&msg,sizeof(struct header) + MAXPAYLOAD,...);

    paylen = msg.info.payload_length;

    if (rawlen != (sizeof(struct header) + paylen))
        // error ...

    memcpy(buf,&msg.payload[0],paylen);

    return paylen;
}
```

The receiver can check the magic number and sequence number to look for corruption or missing/dropped packets, etc.

---

In fact, you can probably get more efficiency by using `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` since they allow you to send a single message using a scatter/gather list. (i.e.) The data would not have to be copied in/out using `memcpy` from the message struct [you'd only need `struct header`], so closer to zero copy buffering.

---

Another option may be to use the `MSG_PEEK` flag with the `recvfrom/recvmsg`. I've never used this myself, but it would be something like:

1. Do `recvmsg` with length of `sizeof(struct header)`  with `MSG_PEEK` flag
2. Do second `recvmsg` with length of `sizeof(struct header) + msg.info.payload_length`

This is just a nicety of not having to always provide a maximum sized buffer. Since it involves *two* syscalls, it may be a bit slower. But, it might allow allow some tricks with selecting a payload buffer from a pool, based on the type of message and/or length

Answer (score 1):

Unlike TCP which is a stream-based protocol, meaning that calls to `recv` don't exactly correspond to a call to send, UDP is packet based meaning that each `recvfrom` matches with exactly one `sendto`.  This also means you need to take care of how large each message you send is.

If you send a UDP datagram that is larger that what can be contained in a IP packet, the UDP message will be fragmented across multiple UDP packets, increasing the chance of data loss.  That's something you want to avoid.  Also, if you're using IPv6, you'll get an error when you attempt to send because IPv6 doesn't support fragmentation.

What does this mean in relation to what you're doing?  It means that, roughly speaking, your messages shouldn't be any larger than about 1450 bytes, so you can use that value as the size of your input buffer.  Then you can use the return value of `recvfrom` to see how many bytes were actually read.  If your messages are larger than that, you should break them up into multiple messages.

As with any UDP based protocol, you need to account for the case where messages get lost and they need to be retransmitted, or if messages come out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Actually answer to this question was quite simple.

Given:

```
unsigned char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
int bytes = fill_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer)): // Returns number of filled bytes.
sendto(socket, buffer, bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))
```

The return value of `recvfrom` tells us how many bytes are received, although we make a full read,

```
int bytesReceived = recvfrom(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
// Process bytesReceived number of bytes in the buffer
```